# How to fetch a specific node data from multiple Nodes from Firebase to this Layout?

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, chat

I successfully managed to load each user specific UID in the app's layout. Here is the image:

[image: image description here]

At the time of registration, I also saved the users email and password to database under "Users" node. Here is the database screenshot:

[image: description]

As it is seen clearly, all the Messages are saved under "MessageTest" node and the UserName and Email are saved Under "Users" Node.

This is the Model class to save name and email to database:

```
public class GetUserName {

String name,email;

public GetUserName(String name, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

Here is my ChatModel class:

```
    public class ChatModel {

    String messages;
   String username;
    public ChatModel() {
    }
    public ChatModel(String messages, String username) {
        this.messages = messages;
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }
    public void setMessages(String messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
```

This is the code that executes when user types a message and clicks on send Button:

```
private void postMessages() {
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MessageTest");
    Log.e("Reference is : ", String.valueOf(databaseReference));
    String actual_msg = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    if (actual_msg.matches("")) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ChatActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Failed")
                .setMessage("Enter all fields/check Internet Connection")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                }).show();
    } else {
        ChatModel chatModel = new ChatModel(actual_msg, mAuth.getUid());
        String id = database.push().getKey();
        database.child(id).setValue(chatModel).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Message Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    editText.setText("");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Message Sent Failed !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

This is how Messages are loaded:

```
  private void loadMessages() {
    msgRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MessageTest");
    Log.e("path1", msgRef.toString());
    msgRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            chatModelList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ChatModel p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(ChatModel.class);
                chatModelList.add(p);
            }
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatModel> options =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatModel>()
                            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MessageTest"), ChatModel.class)
                            .build();
            chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(options, ChatActivity.this, chatModelList);
            chatAdapter.startListening();
            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
            String current_counts = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ChatActivity.this));
        }
```

This is the ChatAdapter's `onBind()`:

```
 @Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ChatModel model) {

    ChatModel model1 = chatModelList.get(position);
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    holder.messages.setText(model1.getMessages());
    holder.userName.setText(model1.getUsername());

}
```

I have tried everything but unable to replace the UID with the username.

Comment: @Stratubas Added Sir, please check

Comment: @Rohit can you explain more properly which node you want to retrieve.

Comment: @Ashish yes Sir, as in screenshot above ,as a user posts a Message, you can see along with the message, the UID is shown. I just wanted to replace the UID of the user posting the message with the name from "Users" node.

Comment: @Rohit Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you to retrieve the value from database and push it in another node. But i have doubt of `addOnCompleteListener` available in Firebase Realtime Database ?

```
DatabaseReference databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().child("Users").child(mAuth.getUid);
databaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            ChatModel chatModel = new ChatModel(actual_msg, name);
            String id = database.push().getKey();
            database.child(id).setValue(chatModel).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Message Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        editText.setText("");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Message Sent Failed !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: Legend Comes in Different Forms, you came in the form of an Anime Character ;).  Thanks You SO much

Comment: :) Thank you again, Now i can proceed further